# c# inline string options - for embedded double quotes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I use the @ prefix with my inline strings quite often, to support multi-line strings or to make string with quotes a little more readable. Having to still double up the inline quotes is still somewhat of a pain, so this made me wonder if there was still another option in .net that would allow strings to maintain their doublequotes without requiring some form of delimiting? Something like a CDATA section in xml? I've searched a bit and didn't find anything, but thought I'd ask here in case I've overlooked some .Net feature (perhaps even a recent one in version 4 or 4.5)

update: I've found that vb.net has "XML Literals" that allow defining xml snippets directly inline with the source. This looks pretty close to what I'd like c# to do...

Comment: It helps a little with quotes but not much - it allows you to use "" instead of \"... again, not much help

Comment: also, @ allows multi-line strings, so it is definitely for more than url/path strings

Comment: 100% with @AdamHouldsworth here - sounds like this stuff belongs in a resource file and not jammed into a C# source code file somewhere.

Comment: as an option: create wrapper for string class, define casts from/to string, overload some operator (for instance, `operator &`  ) that will add quotes. Then represent string as concatinations like `var str = (string)(new Wrapper() + "some attr =" & "value in quotes" + "other attr=" & "value in quotes"`). second option: simply define extention method that will wrap passed string by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If there was something that would do what you want, than we wouldn't need to "escape" double quotes.

I like to use @ when writing dynamic HTML in code. But static strings do belong to resources. Even ones that have dynamic values, for example, "Application error. Error Message: {0}". Then you use `string.format` to form the output.

Comment: Your first line doesn't hold true. You would always need to escape something but it wouldn't have to be the double quotes. eg javascript allows you to delimit strings with single or double quotes. This means if you want to declare the string `He said "why me?"` then you could do `teststring = 'He said "why me?"'`. The OP was asking if there was anything allowing alternative syntax in C# (which there isn't but that doesn't make your first line any more true).

Comment: Chris, is this better now? But I give you one up for this

Comment: The first line still doesn't seem to serve much purpose and seems to be circular logic. The feature doesn't exist and you can't really use a logical argument to explain that. Its just a fact.